# Дополнительное условие выборки MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть простой результат выборки из базы

```
param:1,  sub:1
param:1,  sub:2
param:1,  sub:3
param:1,  sub:4

param:2,  sub:1
param:2,  sub:2
param:2,  sub:3
param:2,  sub:4

param:3,  sub:1
param:3,  sub:2
param:3,  sub:3
param:3,  sub:4
```

Как поставить дополнительное условие в WHERE, если входящая задача выглядит так:
выбрать из группы param:2, только sub:3, а из param:1, sub:2 и sub:3 оставив данные в других группах param, а финальная выборка после этого входящего условия должна выглядеть так:

```
param:1,  sub:2
param:1,  sub:3

param:2,  sub:3

param:3,  sub:1
param:3,  sub:2
param:3,  sub:3
param:3,  sub:4
```

Comment: Как я решил эту задачу ... AND (param =2 AND sub = 3 OR param !=2), работает, но это ли правильное решение?

Comment: Нормальное вполне себе решение... Если таблица (и результат) весьма пухлая, а план показывает игнорирование индекса по (param,sub) - можно попробовать UNION двух запросов (первый с `param !=2`, второй соответственно с `param =2 AND sub = 3`).

Comment: Так, тут выяснилось что решение не верное. Решение: AND (param =2 AND sub = 3 OR param !=2) работает только если нужно выбрать 1 из группы. А если скажем нужно выбрать из первой 2, и из второй парочку - то всё, не работает